# CMS media url problem %7D%22

Tags: magento2, image

I'm having some troubles with images in one cms page.

Using

```
<img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/someimage.png'}}" alt="" />
```

The result on the frontend is

```
<img src="http://www.someurl.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/someimage.png%7D%22" alt="">
```

I guess the %7D is for "}" and %22 for the quotation mark, but no idea why it happens here !?

Does someone have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the special char ¨ (like in ü) in the paragraph above the image was the one breaking the images urls.

To reproduce, create a new page and in the content tab, click "show editor", then past ¨ and insert an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try with double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/someimage.png"}}" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still not working though. I tried with single quotes, double quotes and without quotes.